# Lines on hyperboloid of one sheet

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $V=\{x\in R^3 ; \dfrac{x_1^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{x_2^2}{b^2}-\dfrac{x_3^2}{c^2}=1\}$ $(a,b,c>0)$

Note that for $x\in V$,

$\left(\dfrac{x_1}{a}+\dfrac{x_3}{c}\right)\left(\dfrac{x_1}{a}-\dfrac{x_3}{c}\right)=\left(1+\dfrac{x_2}{b}\right)\left(1-\dfrac{x_2}{b}\right)$

From this, show that through every point ov $V$ run two different straight lines that lie entirely on $V$.

My attemp to do this problem was to take a point $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in V$ and take an arbitrary vector $(u,v,w)$ and the line $(1-t)(x_1,x_2,x_3)+t(u,v,w)$ with $t\in R$, and I've tried to find the vector $(u,v,w)$ that satifies the condition, but it was fruitless. Any hint will appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let vector $y \in \mathbb{R}^3 $ be defined as

$y = (y_1, y_2, y_3) = (x_1, x_2, x_3) + t (u, v, w) $

And suppose that $y$ lies on the hyperboloid for any value of $t$, substitute $y$ in the equation of the hyperboloid,

$ \dfrac{y_1^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{y_2^2}{b^2} - \dfrac{y_3^2}{c^2} = 1 $

Substract from this, the equation of the hyperboloid, then

$ \dfrac{y_1^2 - x_1^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{y_2^2-x_2^2}{b^2} - \dfrac{y_3^2-x_3^2}{c^2} = 0 $

Substitute the expressions for $y_1, y_2, y_3 $ and expand

$ \dfrac{ 2 t u x_1 + t^2 u^2 } {a^2} +\dfrac{ 2 t v x_2 + t^2 v^2 }{b^2} - \dfrac{ 2 t w x_3 + t^2 w^2 }{c^2} = 0 $

If this is to hold for any $t$, then we must have

$ \dfrac{ x_1 u }{a^2} + \dfrac{ x_2 v }{b^2 } - \dfrac{ x_3 w }{c^2} = 0$

and

$ \dfrac{u^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{v^2}{b^2} - \dfrac{w^2}{c^2} = 0$

The first of these two last equations is a plane passing through the origin and the second is a cone with vertex at the origin.  Define

$u' = \dfrac{u}{a} , v' = \dfrac{v}{b}, w' = \dfrac{w}{c} $

Then, the above two equations become

$ \dfrac{x_1}{a} u' + \dfrac{x_2}{b} v' - \dfrac{x_3}{c} w' = 0 $

and

$ u'^2 + v'^2 - w'^2 = 0 $

The solution of the last equation (cone equation) is given parametrically as

$ (u', v', w') = t ( \cos s, \sin s, 1 ) $

Subsititute this into the equation of the plane, and divide by $t$, then,

$\dfrac{ x_1}{a} \cos s + \dfrac{x_2}{b} \sin s - \dfrac{x_3}{c} = 0 $

To solve this trigonometric equation in $s$ , divide through by $\sqrt{ \left(\dfrac{x_1}{a}\right)^2 + \left( \dfrac{x_2}{b} \right)^2 }$, then by defining the angle $\phi$ to be the angle satisfying

$\cos \phi = \dfrac{ \dfrac{x_1}{ a} } {\sqrt{ \left(\dfrac{x_1}{a}\right)^2 + \left( \dfrac{x_2}{b} \right)^2 } }$

$\sin \phi = \dfrac{ \dfrac{x_2}{ b} } {\sqrt{ \left(\dfrac{x_1}{a}\right)^2 + \left( \dfrac{x_2}{b} \right)^2 } }$

Then,

$ \cos \phi \cos s + \sin \phi \sin s = \dfrac{ \dfrac{x_3}{c} }{\sqrt{ \left(\dfrac{x_1}{a}\right)^2 + \left( \dfrac{x_2}{b} \right)^2 } } $

And this equation simplifies to

$ \cos( s - \phi) = \dfrac{ \dfrac{x_3}{c} }{\sqrt{ \left(\dfrac{x_1}{a}\right)^2 + \left( \dfrac{x_2}{b} \right)^2 } } $

Which has two solutions because the right hand side is less than $1$ in absolute value, that is,

$-1 \lt \dfrac{ \dfrac{x_3}{c} }{\sqrt{ \left(\dfrac{x_1}{a}\right)^2 + \left( \dfrac{x_2}{b} \right)^2 } } \lt 1 $

This can be seen from the fact that $\left(\dfrac{x_3}{c}\right)^2 = \left(\dfrac{x_1}{a}\right)^2 + \left( \dfrac{x_2}{b} \right)^2 - 1 $

Thus we have shown that for any point $x$ on the hyperboloid there are two sets of $(u, v, w)$ such the line $y = x + t (u,v,w) $ lies completely on the hyperboloid.